# Can the Telekinetic Projectile spell be used with Sneak Attack?

Tags: spells, rogue, sneak-attack, pathfinder-2e

Can the Telekinetic Projectile spell be used with Sneak Attack? Specially if you have low Dex or Str.

Examples: Throw dagger, arrow, bolt, dart or spear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, if you have the right feat.**

In the first printing Telekenetic Projectile has a typo.

The wording of Telekenetic Projectile requires you to:

> Make a ranged attack against the target

However, ranged attacks do not exist in the rules. There are ranged spell attacks, and ranged strikes.

Thankfully [errata](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) has clarified that it is a Ranged Spell attack.

As a ranged spell attack, [Magical Trickster](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=562) will allow you to use it to make sneak attacks if your target is flat footed.

Comment: Note: this has been fixed with recent errata; Telekinetic Projectile is now formally a spell attack.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, With Magical Trickster

Errata has updated the spell description of [Telekinetic Projectile](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=334) to (emphasis mine):

> Make a *spell* attack...

Therefore Sneak Attack would work with [Magical Trickster](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=562).

Answer (score 2):

### No

The description for [Sneak Attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=10) lists the requirements for taking effect as

> If you Strike a creature that has the flat-footed condition (page 620)
>   with an agile or finesse melee weapon, an agile or finesse unarmed
>   attack, or a ranged **weapon** attack

And the Telekenetic Projectile spell requires you to

> Make a ranged attack against the target

This is not a ranged **weapon** attack as required by Sneak Attack. Further, it is not a spell attack as required by [Magical Trickster](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=562)

> When you succeed at a spell attack roll against a flat-footed foe’s AC
>   and the spell deals damage

and so will not even benefit from Sneak Attack if you have that feat.

### However

From the [General Rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) section on pg 446

> Attack rolls take a variety of forms and are often highly variable
>   based on the weapon you are using for the attack, but there are three
>   main types: melee attack rolls, ranged attack rolls, and spell attack
>   rolls

Which seems to indicate that you can't really have an un-typed "ranged attack" roll. So it then makes the most sense to assume that the reference to "ranged attack" in the Telekenetic Projectile entry means a ranged "spell attack", since the damage component benefits from your spellcasting modifier. If this is the case (and I would rule this way as a GM), then you would be able to benefit from Sneak Attack ***if*** you had the Magical Trickster feat.